# Can one watch video in terminal (command-line)?

Tags: command-line, video

Is there any tool for watching video in command-line? (Don't mind the quality of video)

Anything I can download using `apt` or anything else is appreciated.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: When you're in the text mode(i.e console ,you can get there by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Fn with Fn being 1-7) , using the ```vlc``` command plus the name of the video as the argument works.It renders a nice text-based video with sound.But I cannot replicate that in graphical mode(default mode)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Meet `mpv`, your command line video player.

Yes, you download via `apt`. It is available in the standard Ubuntu repositories.

You *can* mind the video quality: `mpv` is a top quality video player.

However, it looks as if you are *serious* about watching the video in the terminal itself. If that is what you want, then use following command:

```
mpv --no-config --vo=tct <your videofile>
```

However, in that case, please *do not* mind the quality. Yet, no xorg needed: that also works in a virtual console.

Comment: It helped me! Thanks! (yes I will watch video on command line)

Comment: You're welcome! I was first hesitating whether you were just looking for a terminal based video player, but you made it quite clear you really want the video *in* the terminal as well!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use mplayer with the caca video out flag  or with xterm using the ncurses flag
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/160221/68897
terminal

```
$ xterm -fn 5x7 -geometry 250x80 -e "mplayer -vo aa:driver=curses j.mp4

$ CACA_DRIVER=ncurses mplayer -vo caca video.mp4
```

or with vlc

```
% vlc --vout caca somevideo.avi
```

https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Modules/caca/

also mpv as in the previous answer. though if you use a framebuffer terminal you can use `--vo drm` and get full quality resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clear video solution

[timg](https://github.com/hzeller/timg)

```
timg --center /dev/video1
```

[image]